# Sound stopping after some time - Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

This code is called everytime I click a button. After some time when I click the button, the sound is not displayed anymore. I tried to use another music file, and also I tried to use the MediaPlayer instead of SoundPool, but the problem kept happening.

To be more specific about the problem, it is like: I click for 10 times and it is returning the sound, when I click once again it stops

```
public void displaySound(Context context){
        SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        int soundId = sp.load(context, R.raw.bubble_nice, 1);
        sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bubble_nice);
        mPlayer.start();
    }
```

When the sound stops, this is appearing in the log: `E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)`

Comment: I think you should release mPlayer before use new one.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: you should refer BSavaliya's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and found a solution, you can try as follow:

first declare a mediaplayer object gloabally like

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
```

then use following method on click of button.

```
 public void displaySound(Context context) {
    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bubble_nice);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when activity pause you must to pause your Mediaplayer, and activity's onStart() metod you ca call it again. bellow code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mPlayer.reset();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mPlayer.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked better for me with a small modification to BSavaliya's code:
First declare mPlayer as a global variable.

```
 if (mPlayer != null )
 {
     if(mPlayer .isPlaying())
     {   
       mPlayer .stop();
     }    
     mPlayer .reset();
 }
```